# I get errors when trying to paginate my Next JS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to create a pagination function on my Next JS blog, I have been able to limit the Query output but get errors when I try implementing the load more button. My stack is GraphQL, WordPress and Next JS

Here is my code below.

1. api.ts

Here is where I make my API call, this is not all but I am trying to extract the most important part for the sake of clarity.

```
api.ts


import { homepageQuery, blogPosts, blogPostBySlug } from './queries';

const API_URL = process.env.WP_API_URL;

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables = {} } = {}) {
  // Set up some headers to tell the fetch call
  // that this is an application/json type
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  // build out the fetch() call using the API_URL
  // environment variable pulled in at the start
  // Note the merging of the query and variables
  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
  });

  // error handling work
  const json = await res.json();
  if (json.errors) {
    console.log(json.errors);
    console.log('error details', query, variables);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
  }
  return json.data;
}

export async function getHomepageSections() {
  const data = await fetchAPI(homepageQuery);
  return data;
}

export async function getBlogPosts(endCursor = null, taxonomy = null) {
  
  const data = await fetchAPI(blogPosts, { variables: {after:endCursor} });
  return data;
}

// export async function getBlogPosts(endCursor = null, first = 12, taxonomy = null) {
//   const condition = `after: "${endCursor}", first: ${first}, where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: DESC}}`;
//   const data = await fetchAPI(blogPosts, { variables: { condition } });
//   return data;
// }

export async function getBlogPostBySlug(slug) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(blogPostBySlug, { variables: { id: slug } });
  return data;
}
```

2. Queries.ts is Where I houses my GraphQL Query

```
import { getBlogPosts, endCursor } from "./api";




export const homepageQuery = `
query HomepageQuery {
    homepageSections {
      edges {
        node {
          homepage {
            hero {
              animatedwords
              heading
              subtitle
            }
            callouts {
              title
              subtitle
              calloutone {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
              calloutthree {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
              callouttwo {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
            }
            icongrid {
              iconone {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconfive {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconfour {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconsix {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconthree {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              icontwo {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
`;

let condition = `after: "$endCursor",first: 12, where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: DESC}}`

export const blogPosts = `
  query BlogPosts{
    posts(${condition}) {
      edges {
        node {
          author {
            node {
              nickname
            }
          }
          date
          slug
          featuredImage {
            node {
              mediaItemUrl
            }
          }
          title
        }
      }

      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        startCursor
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const blogPostBySlug = `
  query PostBySlug($id: ID!) {
    post(id: $id, idType: SLUG) {
      id
      content
      title
      author {
        node {
          nickname
          avatar {
            url
          }
        }
      }
      date
      featuredImage {
        node {
          mediaItemUrl
        }
      }
   
    }
  }
`;
```

3. Loadmore.js is where I house my Load More Button

```
import React from 'react';
import { getBlogPosts } from '../../../../lib/api';


const LoadMore = ({allPosts, setallPosts}) => {

  

    const handleOnclick = async(event) =>{


    const morePosts = await getBlogPosts(allPosts.pageInfo.endCursor);


   

          let updatedPosts = {
            pageInfo: {
  
            },
            nodes: []
        }
          updatedPosts.pageInfo = morePosts.pageInfo;
  
          allPosts.nodes.map((node) => {
                  updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
              });
  
          morePosts.nodes.map((node) => {
                updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
            });
  
        setallPosts(updatedPosts);
  
  
    }
    return (
      <>
       <button
       
       onClick={handleOnclick}
       >
        Load More
       </button>
      </>
    );
  };
  

  export default LoadMore;
```

4. Result.ts is where I display my blog post list.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  colors,
  useMediaQuery,
  FormControl,
  OutlinedInput,
  InputAdornment,
  Button,
  Avatar,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Divider,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Icon, Image } from 'components/atoms';
import { CardProduct, Section, SectionAlternate } from 'components/organisms';
import { formatDate } from '../../../../../utils';
import { LoadMore } from 'components/molecules';

import {useState} from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  link: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  pagePaddingTop: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(5),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(5),
    },
  },
  sectionAlternate: {
    '& .section-alternate__content': {
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(5),
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(5),
      },
    },
  },
  searchInputContainer: {
    background: theme.palette.alternate.main,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    boxShadow: '0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      border: '0 !important',
    },
    '& .MuiInputAdornment-positionStart': {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-adornedStart': {
      paddingLeft: 0,
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
      padding: 0,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  searchButton: {
    maxHeight: 45,
    minWidth: 135,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      minWidth: 'auto',
    },
  },
  cardProduct: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    '& .card-product__content': {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
  image: {
    objectFit: 'cover',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(0, 0, 20, 0),
  },
  blogContent: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%',
  },
  list: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatarContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  divider: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 0),
  },
  button: {
    minWidth: '100%',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      minWidth: 420,
    },
  },
  answerCount: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1 / 2, 1),
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    background: theme.palette.secondary.light,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 300,
  },
}));

const Result = ({
  data,
  className,
  posts,
  ...rest
}: ViewComponentProps): JSX.Element => {



  const [allPosts, setallPosts] = useState(posts)



  const classes = useStyles();

  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'), {
    defaultMatches: true,
  });

  const BlogMediaContent = (props: ImageProps) => {
    return (
      <Image
        {...props}
        src={props?.node?.featuredImage?.node?.mediaItemUrl}
        className={classes.image}
        lazyProps={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      />
    );
  };

  const BlogContent = (props: any) => (
    <div className={classes.blogContent}>
      <Typography variant="h6" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
        {props.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
        {props.subtitle}
      </Typography>
      <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
      <Divider className={classes.divider} />
      <div className={classes.list}>
        <div className={classes.avatarContainer}>
          <Avatar {...props.author.photo} className={classes.avatar} />
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
            {props.author}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography variant="overline" color="textSecondary">
          {props.date}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={className} {...rest}>
      <SectionAlternate className={classes.sectionAlternate}>
        <Grid container spacing={isMd ? 4 : 2}>
          {allPosts.map((post: any, index: number) => (
            <Grid
              className={classes.link}
              item
              xs={12}
              sm={6}
              md={4}
              key={index}
              data-aos="fade-up"
            >
              <Link href={`/blog/${post.node.slug}`}>
                <CardProduct
                  withShadow
                  liftUp
                  className={classes.cardProduct}
                  mediaContent={
                    <BlogMediaContent {...post} alt={post.node.title} />
                  }
                  cardContent={
                    <BlogContent
                      title={post.node.title}
                      // subtitle={item.subtitle}
                      author={'copyandpost'}
                      date={formatDate(post.node.date)}
                    />
                  }
                />
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          ))}
          {/* <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="large"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Load more
            </Button>
          </Grid> */}

          <LoadMore allPosts={allPosts} setallPosts={setallPosts}/>


        </Grid>
      </SectionAlternate>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Result;
```

5. Here is the error I get when I try to deploy my code to Vercel

[image]

6. Another error when I try to click the loadmore button.

```
src\components\molecules\LoadMore\LoadMore.tsx (13:59) @ endCursor

  11 | 
  12 | 
> 13 |  const morePosts = await getBlogPosts(allPosts.pageInfo.endCursor);
```

7. Here is the error I find in my console.

```
LoadMore.tsx:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endCursor')
    at handleOnclick (LoadMore.tsx:13:60)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:9288:12)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26135:12)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:12)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:3)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:5)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6457:5)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6430:5)
```

Any help I get would be highly appreciated

Comment: you should create a reproducible codebase in order to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I finally solved it, I modified the code this way and it worked.

1. Api.ts

```
import { homepageQuery, blogPosts, blogPostBySlug } from './queries';

const API_URL = 'https://landing.copyandpost.com/graphql/';

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables = {} } = {}) {
  // Set up some headers to tell the fetch call
  // that this is an application/json type
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  // build out the fetch() call using the API_URL
  // environment variable pulled in at the start
  // Note the merging of the query and variables
  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
  });

  // error handling work
  const json = await res.json();
  if (json.errors) {
    console.log(json.errors);
    console.log('error details', query, variables);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
  }
  return json.data;
}

export async function getHomepageSections() {
  const data = await fetchAPI(homepageQuery);
  return data;
}

export async function getBlogPosts(endCursor = null, taxonomy = null) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(blogPosts, {
    variables: { endCursor: endCursor },
  });
  return data;
}

export async function getBlogPostBySlug(slug) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(blogPostBySlug, { variables: { id: slug } });
  return data;
}
```

2. Queries.ts

```
export const homepageQuery = `
query HomepageQuery {
    homepageSections {
      edges {
        node {
          homepage {
            hero {
              animatedwords
              heading
              subtitle
            }
            callouts {
              title
              subtitle
              calloutone {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
              calloutthree {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
              callouttwo {
                title
                subtext
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                }
              }
            }
            icongrid {
              iconone {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconfive {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconfour {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconsix {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              iconthree {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
              icontwo {
                description
                icon
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
`;

//let condition = `after: "$endCursor",first: 12, where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: DESC}}`;

export const blogPosts = `
  query BlogPosts($endCursor: String) {
    posts(after: $endCursor,first: 12, where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: DESC}}) {
      edges {
        node {
          author {
            node {
              nickname
            }
          }
          date
          slug
          featuredImage {
            node {
              mediaItemUrl
            }
          }
          title
        }
      }

      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        startCursor
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const blogPostBySlug = `
  query PostBySlug($id: ID!) {
    post(id: $id, idType: SLUG) {
      id
      content
      title
      author {
        node {
          nickname
          avatar {
            url
          }
        }
      }
      date
      featuredImage {
        node {
          mediaItemUrl
        }
      }
   
    }
  }
`;
```

3. Loadmore.ts where I get the errors was modified as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { getBlogPosts } from '../../../../lib/api';

const LoadMore = ({ allPosts, setallPosts, pageInfo }) => {
  const handleOnclick = async event => {
    const morePosts = await getBlogPosts(pageInfo.endCursor);

    let updatedPosts = {
      pageInfo: {},
      nodes: [],
    };
    updatedPosts.pageInfo = morePosts.pageInfo;

    allPosts.map(node => {
      updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
    });

    morePosts.posts.edges.map(node => {
      updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
    });

    setallPosts(updatedPosts.nodes);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={handleOnclick}
        variant="contained"
        size="large"
        color="primary"
      >
        Load More
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoadMore;
```

4. result.ts Here is where I render my button

```
/**
 * Caution: Consider this file when using NextJS or GatsbyJS
 *
 * You may delete this file and its occurrences from the project filesystem if you are using react-scripts
 */
import React from 'react';
import BlogSearch from 'views/BlogSearch';
import Main from 'layouts/Main';
import WithLayout from 'WithLayout';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { getBlogPosts } from '../../lib/api';

const BlogPage = ({ posts }): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      {' '}
      <Head>
        <title>Copy and Post - Blog</title>
        <meta
          property="og:title"
          content="Copy and Post - Blog"
          key="Copy and Post"
        />
      </Head>
      <WithLayout
        component={() => <BlogSearch posts={posts} />}
        layout={Main}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default BlogPage;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = await getBlogPosts();

  return {
    props: {
      ...posts,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is clear... you are not exporting the endCursor function on you `api.ts` file.

if you could post the complete `api.ts` file it will be better for helping you

Comment: okay, Iill do that now, I'll update the Question

Comment: Any help? kindly go through the questions again

Answer (score 0):

as I said before. You are not exporting the `endCursor` function on you `api.ts` file.

You are trying to use it on your `Queries.ts`, here:

```
import { getBlogPosts, endCursor } from "./api";
```

but if you look inside your `api.ts` file, you wont see any function called `endCursor`.

So, the error text is pretty clear.

Maybe you removed that function by mistake or something...

Comment: I resolved that already can you help debug the rest code, I cant paginate when I click the load more button